# Permalinks to dynamic generated content

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, permalinks

On this project I am working on, there is a portfolio and a project page.
The project page is dynamically generated using PHP, and I am trying to find a way to create a permalink to these generated pages.

So on the Portfolio page there will be entries that when clicked, it will take you to the generated project page following a template with static links (i.e. menu links, style-sheet links etc...).

So what is the best way to do this / to link to the generated content?

Note: I have tried re-write rules in htaccess but these don't seem to work.

Comment: Provide some examples to clarify what you need.

Comment: link this mate: `http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/php/project.php?project=anythingHere` to `http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/php/project/anythingHere`

Comment: I have already answered your previous question and answered this part as well. See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
http://www.website.com/index.php?id=abc
```

Then in PHP do this...

```
<?php

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    //do whatever you want with the id
    //to add more variables to the URL use &anothervariable=abc
?>
```

Rewrite rules are to make the URL look more appealing, like...

```
http://www.website.com/p/abc
```

EDIT:

Make sure that you have mod_rewrite installed in Apache

Then in .htaccess...

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^php/project/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ php/project.php?project=$1
```

Comment: We have managed to to the first bit, but regarding the re-write, here is what we have now: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^loaidesign\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.loaidesign\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^clients$ "http\:\/\/loaidesign\.co\.uk\/billing\/index\.php" [R=301]` what shall we do with it?

Comment: Edited my answer for you

Comment: We have, and it is actually re-writing them, however it re-writes all the static links within the page as well, i.e. all the style-sheet links have changes as well which break the styling... you know what I mean mate?

Comment: Just make sure you use the full url for the stylesheets and javascript. Or add a slash in front of the path.